# Create a specific alphanumeric sequence on Python

Tags: python, url, python-requests, sequence, alphanumeric

The British Library has a large amount of high-quality scans of books which are available for downloading. Unfortunately, their tool for downloading more than one page at a time does not work. For this reason, I've been trying to create a Python script with the Requests module that will download every page of a given book.

The jpg of every page has a specific url - in this case, that of the first page is https://api.bl.uk/image/iiif/ark:/81055/vdc_000000038900.0x000001/full/2306,/0/default.jpg and that of the second is https://api.bl.uk/image/iiif/ark:/81055/vdc_000000038900.0x000002/full/2306,/0/default.jpg. Extrapolating from the first nine pages (in this example, the book is 456 pages long), I naively created the following script:

```
import requests

base_url = "https://api.bl.uk/image/iiif/ark:/81055/vdc_000000038900.0x0000"
for i in range(1, 456):
    target_url = base_url + str(i) + "/full/2306,/0/default.jpg"
    r = requests.get(target_url)
    with open('bl_' + str(i) + '.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
    print(target_url)
```

This worked for the first 9 pages, but unfortunately, pages 10-15 are not 0000010-0000015, but 00000A-00000F. And the complications do not end here: pages 16-25 are 10-19, but with one leading 0 less (likewise 3-digit numbers have 2 zeros less, etc.). After that, pages 26-31 are 1A-1F, after which pages 16-25 are 10-19, after which pages 26-31 are 1A-1F, after which pages 32-41 are 20-29, after which pages 42-47 are 2A-2F. This pattern continues for as long as it can: up to page 159, which is 9F. After this, in order to remain in two digits, the pattern changes: pages 160-169 are A0-A9, pages 170-175 are AA-AF, pages 176-191 are B0-BF, and so on until page 255 which is FF. After this, pages 256-265 are 100-109, pages 266-271 are 10A-10F, pages 272-281 are 110-119, pages 282-287 are 11A-11F, and so on until page 415 which is 19F. After this, pages 416-425 are 1A0-1A9, pages 426-431 are 1AA-1AF, pages 432-441 are 1B0-1B9, and so on in this pattern until page 456, which is the final page of the book.
Evidently there is an algorithm generating this sequence according to certain parameters. Just as evidently, these parameters can be incorporated into the Python script I am trying to create. Sadly, my meagre coding knowledge was more than exhausted by the modest scriptlet above. I hope anyone here can help.

Comment: Look up the hexadecimal (base 16) numbering system. That's how the pages are being numbered. You can use f-strings and string formatting to get the proper number of leading zeros.

Comment: Just need to perform a hexadecimal to decimal conversion, is all.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I suspected this was a rather banal sequence but had no name for it!

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `str(i)` with `f"{i:06x}"` should give the correct numbering in hexadecimal over 6 zero padded digits in the URL.

Comment: Thanks! The way the code ended up looking is 
```base_url = "https://api.bl.uk/image/iiif/ark:/81055/vdc_00000003237E."  
for i in range(1, 359):  
    target_url = base_url + "0x{0:0{1}X}".format(i,6) + "/full/2306,/0/default.jpg"  
    r = requests.get(target_url)  
    with open('bl_' + str(i) + '.jpg', 'wb') as f:  
        f.write(r.content)  
    print(target_url)```